# How to check that the variable in a different class has been updated?

Tags: java, swing, oop, class, object

Not sure if this has been asked before, it's a bit difficult to explain.

I have 2 classes, Class A and Class B

Class A creates an instance of Class B (which is a dialog box using JDialog).
The user is then asked for text input (stored in a String variable).

How do I tell Class A that the user has now updated the variable and get a copy of it?

Using Java Swing btw,

Thanks

T

Comment: Why can't you use the actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) for the textbox to monitor and let ClassA know that the value is being changed?

Comment: I am using it when the user clicks an OK button to update the variable, but it's updating the variable in Class B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the dialog is modal, then the code is blocked until the dialog is closed:

```
dialog.setVisible(true);
// blocked here until the dialog is closed. The dialog stores the input in a
// field when OK is clicked in the dialog
if (dialog.getTextInputtedByTheUser() != null) {
    ...
```

If the dialog is not modal, then you need to make it call a callback method when the validation happens. This is what MyFrame would contain

```
private void showDialog(
    MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog(this);
    dialog.setVisible(true);
}

public void userHasInputSomeText(String text) {
    // do whatever you want with the text
    System.out.println("User has entered this text in the dialog: " + text);
}
```

and in MyDialog:

```
private MyFrame frame;
public MyDialog(MyFrame frame) {
    super(frame);
    this.frame = frame;
}
...
private void okButtonClicked() {
    String text = textField.getText();
    frame.userHasInputSomeText(text);
}
```

Comment: what would be MyFrame? atm I'm only using  
private final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();

Comment: MyFrame is the object which contains the method to call back. It could be of any type. It's just that it's the object which has to do something with the text entered by the user. It's the instance of Class A in your example.

Comment: Could you show me what Class A should look like, not sure I fully understand

Comment: Ahh, this is driving me crazy, I'm passing in some strings to the dialog box so that they have some default values in the textfields so can't use new MyDialog(this);

Comment: And if I replace MyFrame with the name of Class A then super(frame); doesn't work

Comment: What prevents you from adding an argument to your constructor? In my example, I considered that Class A was a frame. If it isn't, pass the parent frame to your Dialog constructor, and call super(parent), and also pass ClassA as another argument.

Comment: think I've got it, just added new JFrame() to class A and changed to  super(frame); to  super(frame,true);

Answer (score 4):

In general, [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) deals with such cases